# ideaVim action mapping with highlighted text

Tags: intellij-idea, action, shortcut, ideavim

Even thought it is pretty clear how to map shortcuts to IDE actions (e.g. noremap g action GotoClass) I've been trying for a while to make such kind of mapping to work with highlighted text in visual mode. What I want to accomplish is simply to have a custom map that works like the innate IDE action since when in visual mode and typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on macs) the action fill automatically the search with the highlighted text in visual mode. This doesn't work with the ideaVim remap, do you have any clue on how to accomplish that?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

`:action` commands currently don't work with the visual mode / text selections. Feel free to comment / vote for [VIM-862](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-862).